# Set dynamic text within page templates in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am quite new to creating websites with WordPress so I might ask a question which is quite straightforward but I could not find any suitable tutorials/answers to guide me.

I want to create dynamic text elements which I can edit within Wordpress. I have created a full website in HTML, CSS, and Javascript and I converted it to Wordpress pages.

Let's have a look for example to my about page:
**about.php**

```
<?php
    get_header();
    // Template Name: About
?>
<div class="row fullwidth">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 about-section-right">
        <h2>Titel example</h2>
        <p>A very long text.....</p>
        <p>Another very long text</p>
        <a href="contact" class="btn">Contact <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>

</div>
<?php
    get_footer();
?>
```

Now I want to be able to edit the title (`<h2>`) and text (`<p>`) and hyperlink (`<a>`) text in Wordpress. So that I can change the title etc.

I tried to use Advance custom fields by calling: the_field() or by using a shortcode but the text did not show up on my page.

So my question is: is Advanced custom fields the best way to do this because I can not make it work and are there other ways of achieving editing text within Wordpress.

Comment: Yes, Advance custom fields is good plugin to add cstom fields to post, page, and etc. The other way use Wordpress default "custom fields" can see page screen options and enable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pages just use the WordPress loop: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

```
    <?php
        get_header();

if(have_posts()):
while(have_posts()): the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="row fullwidth">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 about-section-right">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php
endwhile;
endif;

        get_footer();
    ?>
```

You create a page "About" in the backend in "Pages" and here you go. All contents within `the_content();` are created by the WYSIWYG editor of the page.

Custom fields are for adding any custom or specific information to a post or page.

*Most probably you do not need an extra template file for your about page and you can use a page.php file for all pages.*

You can conditionally include data depending on custom fields and/or the page you are on.

Read more about custom fields here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

... and about conditional tags here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

It will help you understanding it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you perhaps tell me what you mean by using an extra template file for my about page?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.chipbennett.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/WordPressTemplateHierarchy.rev3_.png

Comment: Usually you have a file page.php which is responsible for displaying all your pages. If your about page is somehow special you put additional information into custom fields. For special styling you may also use the body class.